# Execute windows cmd command from python with args

Tags: python-2.7

so I want to execute a cmd command from python with args and get the output. Example:

```
console.py "dir c: >> C:\test\cmdoutput.txt"
```

This is my python (2.7) code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.run(str(sys.argv))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Solo\PycharmProjects\Hacking\Console.py", line 6, in <module>
    subprocess.run(str(sys.argv))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Answer (score 0):

`.run` was only added in Python 3.5 as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

> The run() function was added in Python 3.5; if you need to retain compatibility with older versions, see the [Older high-level API section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio).

You should probably use one of `call`, `check_output` or `check_call`